# Flink SQL nested elements Avro

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I have Avro schema that contains nested structure and when querying using Flink SQL, we are getting below error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError
        at org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.SqlParserPos.sum_(SqlParserPos.java:236)
        at org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.SqlParserPos.sum(SqlParserPos.java:226)
        at org.apache.calcite.sql.SqlIdentifier.getComponent(SqlIdentifier.java:232)
        at org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.DelegatingScope.fullyQualify(DelegatingScope.java:416)
        at org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl$Expander.visit(SqlValidatorImpl.java:5733)
        at org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl$Expander.visit(SqlValidatorImpl.java:5718)
        at org.apache.calcite.sql.SqlIdentifier.accept(SqlIdentifier.java:317)
```

Example Schema:

ROW<`col1` VARCHAR(2147483647), `postalAddress` ROW<`addressLine1` VARCHAR(2147483647), `addressLine2` VARCHAR(2147483647), `addressLine3` VARCHAR(2147483647)>>

Example SQL:

```
insert into CSVSink
select
col1,
postalAddress.addressLine1 as address
from myStream
```

In Flink SQL, How to select nested elements ?

Comment: Is that the stacktrace of the exception ??

Comment: Yes. Issue is resolved. Flink SQL seems case sensitive.